# Maven : Build project batch

Tags: java, maven

i have some problems for generate project with Maven (Windows).

First, i use the command "mvn archetype:generate" -> No problem

Second, i try to build project with batch with :

```
mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetype -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven.archetype.quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DgroupId=org.example.demo -DartifactId=ticket.batch -Dpackage=org.example.demo.batch
```

But i have the error : BUILD FAILURE :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) on project ticket: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetype:maven.archetype.quickstart:1.1)
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you'are searching for an archetype that does not exists as the exception "says".

You're propably seaching for this one :

```
maven-archetype-quickstart
```

and not the original

```
maven.archetype.quickstart
```

Here is the basic command (you have to had your customs options after theses ones):

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4
```

Don't hesitate to accept as an answer if it help :)

if no i will came back